# How to retrieve username after authentication is successful?

Tags: php, symfony, oauth-2.0

I am using Gitlab authentication in my current symfony project. I am using following two packages.

- omines/oauth2-gitlab
- knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle

Inside my `security.yaml` file

```
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            id: App\Security\UserProvider
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\GitlabAuthenticator

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/connect, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

This is working fine and it is storing cookie `PHPSESSID`. I need to retrieve the username after successful login.

Answer (score 1):

It is very very simple. Just use `$this->getUser()`.

```
public function index()
{
    /** @var \App\Entity\User $user */
    $user = $this->getUser();

    return new Response('Well hi there '.$user->getFirstName());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`UserProvider`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserProviderInterface.php) (that's used in login process) [returns](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserProviderInterface.php#L46) a [`UserInterface`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserInterface.php), which represent a User. From it [you can access](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/UserInterface.php#L73) the username.

Now, how to retrieve that user?

Depending on Symfony version, and depending *where* you want to access it, you have several possibilities:

- Symfony <3.2

  - In controller -> you can use `$this->getUser()->getUsername();`
- Symfony >=3.2

  - In controller -> Inject `UserInterface` directly as a dependency ([read more](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-user-value-resolver-for-controllers))

For both cases, if you need the user *not* in controller, you can inject (based on your symfony version) the [`TokenStorage`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/Storage/TokenStorageInterface.php) or the `Security` service (can't find which version supports which, for sure `Security` component [is supported in sf5](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-fetching-the-user-from-a-service)).

If you choose (or are forced) to go with `TokenStorage` (or its interface), you need to perform the following steps:

1. [getToken](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/Storage/TokenStorageInterface.php#L28)
2. check if the token is not `null`
3. [retrieve the username from the token](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/TokenInterface.php#L72) (or optionally [retrieve the whole user](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/TokenInterface.php#L53) and then retrieve the username from there)